# jquery-week-calendar reading JSON data ASP.net

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using VS 2012 and I'm writing a web app. The app is a workplace scheduler and will write and read from `SQL Server`. The database reading/writing is done in `C#` and I don't have any issues with that.

What I need is an example for my front end / JavaScript on reading JSON data for calendar events. The included example does not seem to work for IE or Chrome and I can't make it work. Once I understand how to pass it static JSON data I can do updates from my database.

https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar

```
   data : function(start, end, callback) {
         callback(getEventData());
      }
   });

   function resetForm($dialogContent) {
      $dialogContent.find("input").val("");
      $dialogContent.find("textarea").val("");
   }

   function getEventData() {
      var year = new Date().getFullYear();
      var month = new Date().getMonth();
      var day = new Date().getDate();

      return {
         events : [
            {
               "id":1,
               "start": new Date(year, month, day, 12),
               "end": new Date(year, month, day, 13, 30),
               "title":"Lunch with Mike"
            },
            {
               "id":2,
               "start": new Date(year, month, day, 14),
               "end": new Date(year, month, day, 14, 45),
               "title":"Dev Meeting"
            },
            {
               "id":3,
               "start": new Date(year, month, day + 1, 17),
               "end": new Date(year, month, day + 1, 17, 45),
               "title":"Hair cut"
            },
            {
               "id":4,
               "start": new Date(year, month, day - 1, 8),
               "end": new Date(year, month, day - 1, 9, 30),
               "title":"Team breakfast"
            },
            {
               "id":5,
               "start": new Date(year, month, day + 1, 14),
               "end": new Date(year, month, day + 1, 15),
               "title":"Product showcase"
            },
            {
               "id":6,
               "start": new Date(year, month, day, 10),
               "end": new Date(year, month, day, 11),
               "title":"I'm read-only",
               readOnly : true
            }

         ]
      };
   }
```

Comment: JSON is composed of just objects and arrays. Here's a decent guide: http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp

Comment: I just don't understand how to feed the week-calendar itself JSON data.

Comment: @user2312767 man...even i have got the same issues, how to feed the data from the database to calendar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24783674/asp-net-webforms-jquery-calendar-json/