# ASP.Net WebForms, jQuery Calendar & json

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server, json, calendar

I have a jQuery calendar inside a webForms (ASPX) page. I understand json notation, it's pretty simple using key value pairs. My calendar has an event parameter that can be fed json. Here it is.

Excuse my terminology

```
    events: [
    {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: new Date(y, m, 1),
        backgroundColor: "#f56954", 
        borderColor: "#f56954"
    },
    {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
        end: new Date(y, m, d - 2),
        backgroundColor: "#f39c12",
        borderColor: "#f39c12"
    },
    {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
        allDay: false,
        backgroundColor: "#0073b7",
        borderColor: "#0073b7"
    },
    {
        title: 'Lunch',
        start: new Date(y, m, d, 12, 0),
        end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
        allDay: false,
        backgroundColor: "#00c0ef",
        borderColor: "#00c0ef"
    },
],
```

At this point I do not want the user to interact with the page. I am only concerned with populating this jQuery json to get populated with a title, start date and end date from my a .Net Object Data Source. Nothing fancy, I don't mind the information being displayed as json on the front end. This app is behind a login so none of the pages are public facing.

I have never used SQL Server to populate the json data. I have read a few threads that seem like the solutions are more for cases where information is getting passed to the front end and then persisted to the backend.

I have found this thread which askes the same question, but there are no answers.
[jquery-week-calendar-asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16177470/jquery-week-calendar-reading-json-data-asp-net)

Can anyone steer me in the right direction. I'm fumbling trying to find the right recipe of tools to get this done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to call a method on the server via AJAX. This method should return JSON, like so:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] 
public List<Event> GetEvents()
{
   // return someDbQueryToRetrieveYourEvents().ToList();
}
```

**EDIT** - added calendar plugin specific AJAX call

The AJAX might look like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').weekCalendar({
        data: function(start, end, callback) {
            $.getJSON("calendarevents.json", {
                start: start.getTime(),
                end: end.getTime()
            }, function(result) {
                callback(result);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Does this help?

Comment: It confirms that it is probably easy. But to be honest. I don't know exactly what to do with this. I'm assuming I need to create a SQL DataSource and configure it to output the values I need. Then I create this WebMethod that takes that SQL Datasource and returns it as a list which can then be iterated though. 

Not sure how calling function(response ) from jquery will then populate the proper key value pairs using the list..? Did I tell you I hate WebFroms and I'm very noob?

Comment: For the data source, you're right in that you'll have to connect to your database (SQL server or whatever). For WebForms, EntityFramework will probably be the easiest. From EntityFramework's DbContext, you can return your events stored in your database to your calendar object via the AJAX request I demonstrated in the answer. From there, your calendar plugin does the rest according to its documentation.

Comment: This makes more sense. I think with my partners knowledge of Web Methods and my knowledge of JavaScript I might be able to figure it out now. 1 Question. I shouldn't need to install any json nuget packages or anything should I. This solution since it only requires populating the json and doesn't require persisting back to the DB should be doable with some basic VS toolbox magic or some hand coding right?

Comment: I appreciate you getting me this far. This is a huge help. I'll let you know if I get it working! Luckily I have some time to work on it.

Comment: @EricB When using WebMethod (ASMX) technology, it's best to use a JSON serialization library (Json.NET is the #1 recommended library). The `ResponseFormat=JSON` thing is hit and miss.

Comment: *NOTED* I appreciate all the extra information. I have installed Json.Net in MVC projects so I am familiar. Just never dug into it myself.